# Shiny App to Create Data Frame & Table Based on User Inputs

Tags: r, shiny, reactive

I am in the process of building a shiny app and have a challenge that I thought would be pretty basic (famous last words).

Basically, I want to create an app that populates a data frame (which is visualized through a data table in shiny) where the content of the table is created purely by user inputs.  I have shared my working code below, which uses a combination of selectInput, radio buttons, numeric inputs and dates to populate a data frame.

The only wrinkle is that I only want the table to be created/displayed when an actionButton is clicked (the "submit" button below) and overwritten each time the button is clicked.

The challenge I am running into is the appropriate eventReactive/observeEvent structure needed to both generate the data frame and output the table in the app.

Any assistance is appreciated.

```
library(DT)
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(shinythemes)
library(shinyWidgets)

ui <- fluidPage(
  
  # Open navbar page and customize the theme
  navbarPage(
    title = "App",
    theme = shinytheme("darkly"),
    tags$head(tags$style(HTML('.navbar-static-top {background-color: #375A7F;}',))),
  ),
  
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      # Date selector
      dateRangeInput("dates", label = h3("Date range")),
      # Select Input
      selectInput("select", 
                  label = h3("Choose a value"), 
                  choices = c(1,2,3,4,5),
                  multiple = TRUE,
                  selectize = TRUE),
      # Numeric Inputs
      textInput("numbers", label = h3('Enter numbers separated by ";"'), value = "0.00"),
      # Radio
      radioButtons("radio", label = h3("Choose an option"),
                   choices = list("A" = 1, "B" = 2, "C" = 3), 
                   selected = 1),
      # Action Buttons
      fluidRow(
        # Update 
        actionButton("submit", label = "Calculate"),
        # Clear Selections
        actionButton("reset", label = "Reset")
      ),
    
    ),
    
    fluidPage(

      fluidRow(
        DTOutput('table')
      )
    )
  ) # Close sidebar
) # Close fluidPage


################################################################################
##Server
################################################################################
server <- function(input, output) {

  df = data.frame(input=character(), date=as.Date(), radio=character(), numbers=as.numeric())
  
  eventReactive(input$submit, {
    df = cbind(input$select, input$dates, input$radio, input$numbers) %>% as.data.frame()
  })
  
  output$table = renderDataTable({
    if (is.null(df)) {return()}
    
    df()
  })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An `eventReactive` is meant to assign a value to something. Instead use an `observeEvent`. Additionally, I made `df` a `reactiveVal` which could be easily updated inside the `observeEvent`. Finally, I fixed several other issues in your code.

Still be aware that you app requires a lot more effort to deal with all the issues a user might encounter when using your app, i.e. the app will error when the user does not provide the same number of values for each column. To make your life easier I would suggest to start with an app where the user is only allowed to add one row.

```
library(DT)
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  # Open navbar page and customize the theme
  navbarPage(
    title = "App",
  ),
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      # Date selector
      dateRangeInput("dates", label = h3("Date range")),
      # Select Input
      selectInput("select",
        label = h3("Choose a value"),
        choices = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5),
        multiple = TRUE,
        selectize = TRUE
      ),
      # Numeric Inputs
      textInput("numbers", label = h3('Enter numbers separated by ";"'), value = "0.00"),
      # Radio
      radioButtons("radio",
        label = h3("Choose an option"),
        choices = list("A" = 1, "B" = 2, "C" = 3),
        selected = 1
      ),
      # Action Buttons
      fluidRow(
        # Update
        actionButton("submit", label = "Calculate"),
        # Clear Selections
        actionButton("reset", label = "Reset")
      ),
    ),
    fluidPage(
      fluidRow(
        DTOutput("table")
      )
    )
  ) # Close sidebar
) # Close fluidPage

server <- function(input, output) {
  df <- reactiveVal(
    data.frame(
      input = character(0), 
      date = as.Date(x = integer(0), origin = "1970-01-01"),
      radio = character(0), 
      numbers = numeric(0)
    )
  )

  observeEvent(input$submit, {
    newdat <- data.frame(
      input = input$select, 
      date = input$dates, 
      radio = input$radio, 
      numbers = as.numeric(strsplit(input$numbers, split = ";")[[1]])
    ) 
    df(dplyr::bind_rows(df(), newdat))
  })

  output$table <- renderDataTable({
    df()
  })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

[image]

Comment: Appreciate the insight, this worked for me.  I concur with your comment on robust error handling , that will be my next step.